# How to create n number of public subnets with the true or false condition

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, subnet

How to create n number of public subnets with the true or false condition.

I'm trying to create a 3 public subnets if the publicsubnet falg is true but my condition is going to create only one subnet instead of 3.

cat modules/vpc/vpc.tf

```
resource "aws_subnet" "public_subnets" {
  count                   = var.pubsubnet && length(var.cidr-subnets) != 0 ? 1 : 0
  vpc_id                  = aws_vpc.vaya-vpc.id
  cidr_block              = var.cidr-subnets[count.index]
  map_public_ip_on_launch = true
  availability_zone       = element(data.aws_availability_zones.available.names, count.index)

  tags = {
    Name = format("%s-%s", var.subnet_ids[count.index], var.env)
  }
}
```

cat main.tf

```
module "vpc" {
  source               = "./modules/vpc"
  vpc_name             = var.vpc_name
  cidr-vpc             = var.cidr-vpc
  aws_igw_var          = var.aws_igw_var
  cidr-subnets         = var.cidr-subnets
  private_subnets_cidr = var.private_subnets_cidr
  subnet_ids           = var.subnet_ids
  env                  = var.env
  pubsubnet            = var.pubsubnet
}
```

cat dev.tfvars

```
vpc_name             = "main-vpc"
cidr-vpc             = "x.x.x.x/16"
cidr-subnets         = ["x.x.x.x/24", "x.x.x.x/24", "x.x.x.x/24"]
subnet_ids           = ["pub-sub1", "pub-sub2", "pub-sub3"]
private_subnets_cidr = ["x.x.x.x/24", "x.x.x.x/24"]
env                  = "dev"
pubsubnet            = true
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you have only `1` count in your subnet resource. Instead it should be:

```
count                   = var.pubsubnet != 0 ? length(var.cidr-subnets) : 0
```